# Why is the number of review tasks pending steadily increasing?

Tags: support, review, top-bar

When I first got this number in brown on my black bar (that happens at 10K, right?) it was always in the single digits after cleaning out the queues available to me. It bounced around from 3-8.

[image: 1]

I wondered what the number meant, and Rumtscho explained that it referred to review tasks not available to me.

It was in the single digits for months. It the past few weeks it has steadily increased..10...20...30 now 53. What has changed?

No big deal, it's just a number on my screen, but I'm curious as to why it has increased so suddenly, rapidly and dramatically.

**EDIT:** As of 9am 11/26 Alaska time, my queues are empty and the review tasks number is up again to 52. Come on people! It only takes a few minutes!

**EDIT**: 67

**EDIT** As of 12/9/14, we've been back to single digits (most of the time) for almost a week.

Comment: I did a couple dozen, definitely doesn't just take a few minutes, but yes, I wish we had more reviewers too! (Not surprising people are busy leading up to Thanksgiving though.)

Comment: Just as a side note: when I've attacked the queue, I've often ended up taking action on a large fraction of posts. Please don't hesitate to edit (even if it's only minor fixes) or flag (in borderline cases). And it's probably better to hit "skip" than "looks ok", if there's something you don't feel like fixing at the moment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I *think* this is because review tasks require more than one reviewer to leave the overall queue, and the number there shows how many tasks there are overall, including ones that you've skipped or have already done. Presumably there are very few people here doing the reviews, so if they stop, the tasks will start accumulating.

I went and reviewed ten or so late answers; if your count has dropped now, that's probably what it was!

Comment: Yep, the number is now at 29.

Comment: Incidentally, this is *why* the number reflects *all* pending reviews and not just the number available to the person viewing it - if, despite action on the part of the reviewer, it's steadily increasing... Then stuff isn't getting *done* and the issue needs to be raised.

Comment: @Shog9 Should we write up a meta post - "Calling all regular users please take the time to do review tasks"? With a little digging around I could figure out what prior regular reviewers have kind of gone AWOL, but I don't think that info would be very helpful. Going AWOL is a prerogative, and who is AWOL is really none of my business (IMO). So how do we nudge new reviewers and editors?

Comment: I just cleared out my queue. It's surprising how quickly it can pile up. Lots of new users, though, which is a great thing.